# Segmentation fault (core dumped) during loading shared library in Python ctypes

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I am trying to load C shared library in Python ctypes. (linux)

But It makes a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` during loading the shared library.

That means (if the name of library is `A.so`)

```
import ctypes

ctyps.CDLL("A.so")   #it makes Segmentation fault
```

What I want to know is usually what is a problem if `Segmentation fault` happens during loading the library.

I don't understand it is compiled normally and I don't any call to functions in the library.

Which part lead this error during loading the library?

Comment: Do you have any [`constructor`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) functions that get called by `dlopen`? For an example of this in action, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21794318/205580).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, that was `template` `type` problem in `C++` side.
For example, I defined a class with `template` like below.

```
# a.hpp
template<typename msgType>
class A{
public:
int get(msgType& msg);
...
...
};


#a.cpp
template<typename msgType>
int A<msgType>::get(msgType& msg){
...
}
template int A<std::string>::get(std::string& msg);
```

And then if I use `A` class with other types other than `std::string` somewhere, it leads `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` while loading the C++ shared library.